# Silly mysql_fetch_assoc(): Error

Tags: php, html, mysql

Sorry I am a novice making a simple page that populates a series of divs. I apologize if what I'm missing is rudimentary-

I am getting a

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource on line 56

Line 56 starts:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `all_products`;'); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo '<div class="product">';
echo '<img src="images/product-\'.$row[\'id\'].\'s.jpg" onclick="JavaScript:newPopup(\'images/product-\'.$row[\'id\'].\'.jpg\');">';
echo '<span class="tiger" data-name="show" data-price="show" data-text="Buy Now">\'.$row[\'id\'].\'</span>\'.$row[\'description\'].\'</div>';
}
?>
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated its already been a few hours lol.

-AR

UPDATE---

new code:

```
<?php 
$link = mysqli_connect('ip', 'usr', 'pass');

if (!$link) {
die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
        . mysqli_connect_error());
}
mysqli_select_db($link, "db");
?>

<?php
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `all_products`") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo '<div class="product">';
echo '<img src="images/product-\'.$row[\'id\'].\'s.jpg" onclick="JavaScript:newPopup(\'images/product-\'.$row[\'id\'].\'.jpg\');">';
echo '<span class="tiger" data-name="show" data-price="show" data-text="Buy Now">\'.$row[\'id\'].\'</span>\'.$row[\'description\'].\'</div>';
}
?>
```

I have changed to sqli now I do get multiple divs, one for each row but inside each div is the message

> Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /classes/class.product.php on line 16
>   Invalid Product'.$row['description'].'

UPDATE-

Hopefully some background will help- 
This code:

```
<div class="product">
<img src="images/product-1s.jpg" onclick="JavaScript:newPopup('images/product-1.jpg');">
<span class="tiger" data-name="show" data-price="show" data-text="Buy Now">
1</span>Lorem Ipsum Dolar</div>
```

works perfectly with everything the way it is, the classes are already coded and mysql_ is used primarily.

All I want to do is stick the id# and the desc in there for every row on the table. I guess it cant be done as simply as I thought. I could manually write all that out and get everything working but obviously that is not ideal.

Is there another method that would allow me to execute this outside of whats already happening?

This function:

```
class Product{
var $error = '';
var $msg = '';
public function all(){
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  " . PFX . "products WHERE active = 1");
$products = array();
while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $products[]=$rows;
    }
return $products;
}
```

is already done, can i call this to populate the variables from the db that I need?

Comment: are you connected to mysql?

Comment: http://php.net/mysql_error

Comment: @John I believe so, is it possible to get resource errors when not connected? If I comment out my connection code i get "Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/roshad11/public_html/shop/index.php on line 56"

Comment: check it with: `mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `all_products`;') or die(mysql_error();` it will give you an error if something is wrong.

Comment: @user1572291 `mysql_query` returns false if the query fails. So something is going wrong here. The query seems fine to me, so maybe you did not select the correct database, or the user does not have proper permissions to access the table, or something entirely different. Without knowing why the query fails (the exact error message from `mysql_error()`) we're all just guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is check if `$result` is `false`, see [`mysql_query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

> **Return Values**
>   For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or **FALSE on error**.

or use `or die(...)`

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `all_products`') or die(mysql_error());
```

You should consider switching to `mysqli` or `PDO`, since `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

**Update** to your update:

This doesn't fit together.

- You have no `mysql_num_rows()` in the modified code.
- Don't mix `mysql_*` with `mysqli_*`.
- Finally, variables are not substituted inside single quotes `'`, so I don't see where this error message comes from.

**Update2**:

Since this method doesn't use any object members, you can define it as a static member function

```
public static function all(){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  " . PFX . "products WHERE active = 1");
    $products = array();
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $products[]=$rows;
    }
    return $products;
}
```

and then call it as

```
$products = Product::all();
```

Comment: Okay, So first thank you for helping me I know some of this stuff is very 101 and I hope you aren't annoyed at this point. :P

Will Update Question Shortly-

Comment: Updated. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @user1572291 Please see updated answer. One final word, this is not a question, but a series of questions. As tempting as it might be, you should not cram multiple questions into one. Pose a question, test the answers and ask until *this* question is resolved. But then ask a new questions and give others a chance, to share their knowledge too.